# Changing measures with a slicer: "a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected" error message

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I followed this blog's instructions to create a slicer that would let me swap between measures in a text table: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Dynamically-change-the-information-within-a-visual-via-a-slicer/ba-p/87027

I am getting this error message for the column I am creating in the last step: "a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected":

```
Select level (% favorable) =
SWITCH( TRUE(),
    VALUES ('Measure Dimensions'[Measure]) = "Country", ROUND([c_pct_favorable],1),
    VALUES ('Measure Dimensions'[Measure]) = "State", ROUND([s_pct_favorable],1),
    VALUES ('Measure Dimensions'[Measure]) = "Zip", ROUND([z_pct_favorable],1),
    BLANK())
```

I am basically trying to swap between country, state, and zip code level % favorable survey data.

Note: I had to add the ROUND calculation because I was getting a 'you can't combine fields with different data types' error message.

I tried Googling this error message but didn't find a use case exactly like mine and couldn't figure out the other article's logic and how it applied to my problem.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you are trying to follow the example precisely, it looks like you have swapped the table name and column name in your VALUES functions.  You have VALUES('Measure'[Measure Dimensions]).  But you want VALUES('Measure Dimensions'[Measure]).

Comment: That was a typo on my part, so sorry! I have fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: When you get this error, do you have just one value from 'Measure Dimensions' selected in your slicer?  This report expression won't work unless that filter is being used.

Comment: @RyanB. Omg that worked, thank you so much!!

Unfortunately, when I try to use that 'Select level (% favorable)' field in my text table, I am now getting an error messaging say that Power BI can't determine relationships between two or more fields. The community blog specifically said I should not connect my slicer data table to any of my other tables so now I don't know what to do. If you have any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it! Otherwise, you've already helped me with one step so I'm very grateful! Thank you again and happy Friday!

Comment: For this style of solution, the 'Measure Dimensions' table shouldn't have any relationships to the rest of your model.  So the problem probably lies somewhere else. 
Take a careful look at the three measures and make note of all the tables that are used in their calculation.  Mentally call these "Measure related tables."   Next, look at all the tables that are being used anywhere else in your visual... Mentally call these "Dimensional Tables."  Be sure that each of the "Measure related tables" has a relationship with each of the "Dimensional Tables."

Comment: Ryan B, thank you so much for helping me on a Friday evening! Apologies I'm just seeing this comment. Thanks for your confirmation that there shouldn't be any relationships and for your mental framework. I'm going to think more about this and get back to you if I find something! Thank you again!!